# input looses autocapitalize after setFocus() ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, keyboard, ionic3, ionic4, ionic-native

I have a ion-textarea in my ionic4 project which should default capitalizes the first letter (The shift-arrow on the iOS keyboard is solid).

```
@ViewChild('focusInput', { static: false }) myInput;

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.myInput.setFocus();
          this.nativeKeyboard.show();
        }, 1300);
      }
```

this code set focus in text area but the shift-key is not longer solid and the first letter is not automatically uppercased. How do I force the first letter to be automatically uppercased?

[image]

I've tried using autocapitalize='sentences' (and the other values) on the ion-textarea but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake. `autocapitalize` defaults to `"off"` on `ion-textarea`, so it needs to enable it in order to get the default capitalization to work.

I should have used `autocapitalize='true'` insted of `autocapitalize='sentences'`

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on ion-input, but setting to 'true' (or 'sentenses') does not work for me. I'm on Ionic 7.6.6